# JAVA with SQL: the return value of insert command?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a table of authors : authorID, authorName.
authorID is a pk with auto increment.

I'd like to write a method in java that gets a name from user and adds it to the table. however i need to return the id of the author. is there a way to do that with 1 sql statement?

for example if my code has the command:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO authors " + "VALUES (, '"+ string.get(1) +"')");
```

which string.get(1) is the author name.

Now if i write:

```
ResultSet rs =stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO authors " + "VALUES (, '"+ string.get(1) +"')");
```

it says error as rs is resultset but the returned value is int. is this int the pk of the row that i have inserted?

Comment: No, its the number of rows that has been modified according to your query. A primary key is not always a single integer you know.

Comment: int is the number rows affected means if you have executed one insert then int will be 1.

Comment: where does `string.get(1)` come from? Keep [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) in your mind!

Comment: OKI thx, but i still don't know if i can insert the row and get it's pk with 1 sql statment?

Comment: You can. The code I posted below works.

Comment: It is extremely easy to [find out for yourself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO authors VALUES (, '"+ string.get(1) +"')", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
rs.next();
long pk = rs.getLong(1);
```

Comment: thank you! works like t a charm. only diffrent is that first parameter should be null like: VALUES (null, '"+ string.get(1) +"')

Comment: Or better yet, the OP should use a parametrized query

Comment: Please use a parameterized query. This code as presented is an SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: what if stmt.getGeneratedKeys() throws SQLException, how to delete inserted record?..

Answer (score 5):

Pass Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS while creating `PreparedStatement` `conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);`

and 
`PreparedStatement#getGeneratedKeys()` returns auto generated key after inert.

Comment: What will it it return if the SQL fails, like, for example, the SQL query was wrong?

Comment: on that case it will throw SQL Exception, find more documentation here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()

Answer (score 5):

In order to get last inserted id look at the below code:

```
PreparedStatement stmnt = Conn.preparedStatement("INSERT INTO authors(col1) VALUES (?)", Statement. RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS );
stmnt.setString(col1val);
stmnt.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs=stmnt.getGeneratedKeys();
if(rs.next()){
   System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO authors VALUES (...) returning authorID
```

When you execute it, do so with `executeQuery`. You should get back a `ResultSet` with one row and one column — it will be the ID.

Comment: ResultSet rs =stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO authors " + "VALUES (, '"+ string.get(1) +"' returning authorID)"); doesn't work

Comment: @jeffranz use executeQuery

Comment: ... and move the closing bracket from after `authorID` to before `returning`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is supported by JDBC (haven't used it in a while), but I guess you could try:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (FIELD1, FIELD2) VALUES ('foo', 'bar') RETURNING FIELD3
```

via executeQuery() or, if your jdbc driver doesn't support  `RETURNING` write a simple stored function.

Which RDMBS are you using?